# Updating a table with data from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update the hash and parType columns in table `path` with data from the same table. I can up with the following sql from an answer here on SO, but the update seems to fail me.

What I'm trying to do here, is update all the rows where hash = 0 and parType = 0, with hash = the same rows id and parType = the type value of parent id of that row.

If you'll see my desired results you understand.

Can you help? Never mind my sql.

**Sql**

```
update path t join(
select t1.id, t1.type, t2.parent from path t1, path t2 where t1.parent = t2.id;
) as p on p.id=t.id set hash = t1.id and parType = t1.type;
```

**Before Update**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "hash"  "parType"
"1"     "0"     "0"         "0"     "0"
"2"     "2"     "1"         "0"     "0"
"3"     "3"     "2"         "0"     "0"
"4"     "4"     "3"         "0"     "0"
```

**Desired results**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "hash"  "parType" //parType = the type of the parent
"1"     "0"     "0"         "1"     "0"
"2"     "2"     "1"         "2"     "0"
"3"     "3"     "2"         "3"     "2" -> This is value from the parents type
"4"     "4"     "3"         "4"     "3"
```

**Edit - This works, but I'm still not sure if it's the right way to do it**

```
update path a join(
select t1.id as hash, t2.type as parType from path t1 inner join path t2 on t1.parent = t2.id
) b on a.id=b.hash set a.hash = b.hash , a.parType = b.parType;
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: No error message. Nothing gets update at all.

Comment: @sarwar026 I use only one. I pasted twice by mistake.

Comment: @jmenezes: its ok. btw, `parType` of last row should be `2` instead of `3`, right?

Comment: @sarwar026 I corrected that too. Now the desired results are ok.

Comment: @jmenezes: yes, now it's full ok

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL exact syntax, so I dont want to give you incorrect advice. But I am not sure what you are trying to do. Why would you add the partner type as a column? If the parter gets updated, the value will be stale abd you should update it again.  The value can always be selected with a self-join in a query?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE table1 t LEFT JOIN
(SELECT t1.id,t1.type FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.id>t2.id GROUP BY t1.id) as p 
ON p.id+1=t.id SET t.hash=t.id,t.parType=ifnull(p.type,0)
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0ce5/1)

Comment: parType needs to be the type of the parent row. See my desired results.

Comment: Right, it is. But instead of using the `>` and other things you 've used, would it not be better to use the parent id and main id?

Comment: Its still a inner join,doesnt matter the field,speed wise.

Comment: Some thing on these line, `update path a inner join(
select t1.id, t1.type, t2.parent from path t1, path t2 where t1.parent = t2.id) 
b on a.id=b.id set a.hash = b.id and a.parType = b.type;
`

Comment: Check this: Since you're good at sql, you may see if this is good or bad. This works: `update path a join(
select t1.id as hash, t2.type as parType from path t1 inner join path t2 on t1.parent = t2.id
) b on a.id=b.hash set a.hash = b.hash , a.parType = b.parType;
`

Comment: @jmenezes Sorry jmenezes I had a brain short circuit from the previous query,I don't fell like looking at another.Sorry.

Comment: LOL. You wont believe what I went through for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this please

```
update path t join(
select t1.id, t2.type, t2.parent from path t1, path t2 where t1.parent = t2.id;
              ^^
) as p on p.id=t.id set hash = t1.id and parType = t2.type;
                                                   ^^
```

I've changed the inner join from `t1.type` to `t2.type` and the `ON` condition from `parType = t1.type` to `parType = t2.type`

Comment: Your sql is a replica of the sql from my statement which doesn't work

Comment: this is not replica, you don't read out my comment below the sql. It may not work but it is not replica!

Comment: Check my updated answer. The last one works, but since I did it on my own, there may be errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update t set 
   hash = t.id,
   partype = p.type
from path t 
   left join path p
      on p.id = t.parent
where hash = 0 
   and parType = 0
```

Comment: :-) parType needs to be the type from the parent row.

Comment: Whay does this return an error even when all seems ok? `/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from path t 
   left join path p
      on p.id = t.parent
where hash = 0 
  ' at line 4 */`

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Is that sql is ok, or you see any faults in it?

Comment: Is your sql for MySql?